Dynamically set the text for data template button
I am trying to work on a WPF project, I have a XAML that defines items control as below, and uses Button for Data Template. And It uses Button with hardcoded text as "Text #1/2/3/4". However, I would like to allow the text to dynamically set the text. How should I do it?
Thanks
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="2"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="Cassette_No"  Content="{Binding}"  Height="auto" Width="480" Click="Cassette_Clicked"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <system:String>Text #1</system:String>
    <system:String>Text #3</system:String>
    <system:String>Text #2</system:String>
    <system:String>Text #4</system:String>
</ItemsControl>


if possible, edit your question and add a screenshot of the current result

Instead of adding strings in XAML, assign or bind a collection to the ItemSource property of the ItemsControl. Use for example an ObservableCollection<string>. Whenever you add or remove a string to/from the collection, the UI will update automatically. Alternatively, use a collection of data objects with a string property that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Your event handler Cassette_Clicked will cause memory leak. As it is creating hard reference.
